# Tensorflow 2.0 model always predicting the same label

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, image-classification

I am pretty new to ML and tensorflow, so I was working through the tutorials on tensorflow and copy/pasted one of their models with a custom training loop with a few modifications. Upon training it on the cifar10 dataset over 3 epochs, it achieved a 60 percent training acc and 54 percent validation acc. However, when I loaded it into another script to try and test it with images online, the logits had a nearly identical incorrect spread. 2 of the images tested were from online of a boat and airplane which looked similar to other cifar10 images while the other 2 were from the dataset itself, being a horse and boat. All produced nearly identical logits. What's really weird is that the logits always seem to peak at the fourth label (cat), no matter which model, architecture, or image I use. I've also tried switching optimizers to no avail. What am I missing (feedback regarding the problem itself or anything else about the code is greatly appreciated)?

Model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import layers
import numpy as np
import wandb
import datetime
from datetime import time
from PIL import Image

wandb.init(project='cifar10_seq', sync_tensorboard=True)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(10)
])

model.summary()

# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
# Instantiate a loss function.
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
# Prepare the metrics.
train_acc_metric = keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
val_acc_metric = keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

# dataset
batch_size = 64
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
# x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))
# x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))

# Reserve 10,000 samples for validation.
x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]

# Prepare the training dataset.
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

# Prepare the validation dataset.
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size)


epochs = 3
training_on = True
if training_on:
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print("Start of epoch %d" % (epoch+1,))

        # Iterate over dataset in batches
        for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                # Run the forward pass of the layer.
                # The operations that the layer applies
                # to its inputs are going to be recorded
                # on the GradientTape.
                logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)

                # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
                loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

            wandb.log({"loss": loss_value})
            wandb.log({"train_acc": train_acc_metric.result()})

            # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
            # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
            grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

            # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
            # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

            # Update training metric.
            train_acc_metric.update_state(y_batch_train, logits)

            # Log every 200 batches.
            if step % 200 == 0:
                print(
                    "Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f"
                    % (step, float(loss_value))
                )
                print("Seen so far: %s samples" % ((step + 1) * batch_size))
        # Display metrics at the end of each epoch.
        train_acc = train_acc_metric.result()
        print("Training acc over epoch: %.4f" % (float(train_acc),))

        # Reset training metrics at the end of each epoch
        train_acc_metric.reset_states()

        # Run a validation loop at the end of each epoch.
        for x_batch_val, y_batch_val in val_dataset:
            val_logits = model(x_batch_val, training=False)
            # Update val metrics
            val_acc_metric.update_state(y_batch_val, val_logits)
            wandb.log({"val_acc": val_acc_metric.result()})
        val_acc = val_acc_metric.result()
        val_acc_metric.reset_states()
        print("Validation acc: %.4f" % (float(val_acc),))

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

model.save("cifar10_new.keras")

wandb.finish()
```

Test script:

```
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import layers
import numpy as np


def rescale_images(directory, size):
    im = Image.open(directory)
    im_resized = im.resize(size, Image.LANCZOS)
    im_resized.save(directory)


def prepare_image(directory):

    img = tf.io.read_file(directory)
    tensor = tf.io.decode_image(img, channels=3, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
    input_tensor = tf.expand_dims(tensor, axis=0)

    return input_tensor


model = keras.models.load_model("cifar10_new.keras")

rescale_images("random_images/car.png", (32, 32))
prediction = model.predict(prepare_image("random_images/car.png"))
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(prediction)
print(prediction)
```

The output of each image (softmax):

car:
tf.Tensor(
[[1.0266284e-03 7.7120079e-05 7.0860572e-02 8.8686663e-01 1.8580483e-02
1.7540520e-02 9.1350032e-04 8.7989774e-04 3.2326749e-03 2.1997652e-05]], shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32)

boat:
tf.Tensor(
[[1.0634739e-03 7.8063604e-05 7.0776239e-02 8.8636857e-01 1.8690629e-02
1.7929520e-02 8.5596397e-04 8.9970016e-04 3.3151936e-03 2.2658043e-05]], shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32)

horse:
tf.Tensor(
[[9.7531546e-04 6.9031390e-05 6.4809047e-02 8.9467043e-01 1.7074293e-02
1.7835772e-02 7.6558901e-04 8.5785246e-04 2.9216956e-03 2.0959489e-05]], shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32)

airplane:
tf.Tensor(
[[1.0483327e-03 7.7148259e-05 7.0324250e-02 8.8746655e-01 1.8424451e-02
1.7627772e-02 8.5348362e-04 8.9448754e-04 3.2609249e-03 2.2576383e-05]], shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32)

The images are drastically different so I do not believe it would be because the model actually thinks each of these images are a cat. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I translated the images to float32 when decoding the image, meaning it was scaling from 0, 1 rather than the 0, 255 that my model was trained on. When I changed it to translate to uint8, the model worked.